# What are _Rf_cons and _Rf_allocVector3?

Tags: profiling, rcpp, rcpparmadillo, gperftools

I'm working on an R package that uses Rcpp and RcppArmadillo, and I'm trying to profile one of the main functions in the package to improve its runtime.

I'm using gperftools as [recommended by Dirk](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/papers/ismNov2009introHPCwithR.pdf) and specifically as described in [this blog post](http://minimallysufficient.github.io/r/programming/c++/2018/02/16/profiling-rcpp-packages.html). The top two function calls (by number of profiling samples) are called `_Rf_cons` and `_Rf_allocVector3`.

```
Total: 1881 samples
     471  25.0%  25.0%      527  28.0% _Rf_cons
     308  16.4%  41.4%      309  16.4% _Rf_allocVector3
```

Does anyone know what these functions are, and where they might be called from in Rcpp code? I can't find any references to them via google or in the Rcpp GitHub repo.

Thanks!

Comment: I think if you look at the (old) workshops / tutorials I also show some charts / tables based off the `gperftools` data.  With R being a dynamiclly typed language with a garbage collector there is always _a lot_ else going on.   In essence, you will see measurements for base R functions being called our code.  Such is life.

Comment: Thanks @DirkEddelbuettel! I have the profiling set up to isolate the C++ function (i.e., start_profiler(); call_Rcpp_fn(); stop_profiler()), so do you think that means these are likely to be associated with converting data in or out of base R?

Comment: Yes, very good -- `gperftools` allow that.  _But you still don't get Rcpp without R_ and that is exactly what you are seeing.  The only way to profile your code "purely" is to ... have it hang off its own `main()` (which is often impractical...).

Comment: Thanks! This was quite helpful. The function I'm profiling is an iterative algorithm; I had reduced the number of iterations for testing but I think I went too far. I increased the number of iterations and am seeing more reasonable results (mostly arma functions). 

I do have two follow up questions - 1) the top function call looks like a memory address. Is there any hope of parsing out what that corresponds to? 2) Would you have any suggestions for identifying what code would be calling Rcpp functions such as `internal::primitive_range_wrap__impl__nocast` or `Rcpp_ReleaseObject`? Thank you!